# Dice worker placement game about terraforming a planet

Tags: identify-this-game

I'm looking for a game I played about 3-5 years ago. It was set in space and centred around terraforming a planet (possibly Mars?).

It is a dice worker placement game where you roll dice and each dice is an action that you can use at one of the stations surrounding the planet, depending on the restrictions on numbers at that location.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I found the game: [Alien Frontiers](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/48726/alien-frontiers)